# How to detect SharePoint 2013/2016 authentication mode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication, sharepoint, fba

I need to detect [authentication type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457529.aspx) being used by SharePoint 2013 and 2016. I need to distinguish between ASP.NET Forms (cookies) authentication and Windows (Basi/Digest/NTLM/Ketberos) authentication.

I see that it is possible to detect authentication mode on server side: [Programmatically determine authentication mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794156/programmatically-determine-authentication-mode). But our SharePoint add-in is a pure JavaScript and does not have any server-side code.

Is it possible to detect SharePoint authentication in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should investigate the HTTP headers of your web page.

They can be read through javascript (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)) and contain information regarding the authentication type in use.

Comment: WWW-Authenticate header and Set-Cookies header can give authentication info. However there is no access to these headers in JS without modifying server-side.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're on a standard SharePoint page -- if so, you can use the `_spPageContextInfo` object's  `userId` and `userLoginName` properties.

They come along for the ride when the page is rendered.

From my browser dev tools:

[Check here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123352/how-to-determine-authenticated-status-on-client-side)

Comment: I have examined _spPageContextInfo variable. I do not see anything that can tell me about authentication. Which particular property contains authentication type?